# How can I signin in Gitlab with browser in headless mode?

Tags: firefox, browser, gitlab

For testing reasons I'd like to signin on GitLab.com - with firefox in headless mode.
But when GitLab said 'wait 5 seconds to redirect' this redirection has never done.

How can I solve this problem?
What is going on under the hood?

Thank you

Comment: I'd guess they are detecting your bot and not letting it have access. Use the API instead. https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/

Comment: Thank you. I'll try it then notify my progress.